# Series Expansion of cos with Python

Tags: python, math, series, trigonometry

So, I'm trying to find the value of `cos(x)`, where `x=1.2`.  I feel the script I have written should be fine, however, the value I get out isn't correct.  That is; `cos(1.2)=0.6988057880877979`, for `25` terms, when I should get out: `cos(1.2)=0.36235775`.

I  have created a similar program for calculating `sin(1.2)` which works fine.

Calculating `sin(1.2)`:

```
import math as m

x=1.2
k=1
N=25
s=x
sign=1.0

while k<N:
    sign=-sign
    k=k+2
    term=sign*x**k/m.factorial(k)
    s=s+term

print('sin(%g) = %g (approximation with %d terms)' % (x,s,N))
```

Now trying to calculate `cos(1.2)`:

```
import math as m

x=1.2
k=1
N=25
s=x
sign=1.0

while k<N:
    sign=-sign
    k=k+1
    term=sign*x**k/m.factorial(k)
    s=s+term

print(s)
```

Comment: May I ask why you are not using math.cos(x) ?

Comment: @zoubida13 Probably learning about expansions from Taylor's Theorem. Not everything has to be practical :)

Comment: @zoubida13 he's calculating it using expansion in series. Taylor series ring any bell? :)

Comment: Apologies then, I was just curious :) Doesn't ring a bell to me but maybe you guys can help then if you're familiar with it

Comment: Cosine is an even function. Try starting at k=0 and incrementing by 2 not 1. And start s at 0.

Comment: the variable `s` should be most likely initialized to `1` instead of `x`...

Comment: You've computed (1 - math.exp(-1.2)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting your initial sum to `1.2`, and your representation of the expansion

[image]

is a bit off - we need to account for the even-ness of the function, so increment `k` by 2. Also, without modifying your program structure, you'd have to set the initial variables so they are correctly put to their starting values at the beginning of the first loop. Re-ordering your loop control flow a bit, we have

```
import math as m

x=1.2
k=0
N=25
s=0
sign=1.0

while k<N: 
    term=sign*x**(k)/m.factorial(k)
    s=s+term
    k += 2
    sign = -sign

print(s)
```

Gives

```
0.3623577544766735
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks so much!  Can't believe I overlooked/missed such basic logic!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using the wrong series for the cosine, the [correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions) would be (I highlighted the important differences with `^`):

```
sum_over_n [(-1)**n * x ** (2 * n) / (math.factorial(2 * n))]
#                           ^^^^                     ^^^^
```

that means to add `n`-terms you have something like:

```
def cosine_by_series(x, terms):
    cos = 0
    for n in range(terms):
        cos += ((-1)**n) * (x ** (2*n)) / (math.factorial(2 * n))
    return cos
    # or simply:
    # return sum(((-1)**n) * (x ** (2*n)) / (math.factorial(2 * n)) for n in range(terms)
```

which gives:

```
>>> cosine_by_series(1.2, 30)
0.3623577544766735
```